# Django Admin Filter by one to many relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm wanting to create a filter so that I can see whether or not a (reverse foreign key?? field is null or not).

Eg:

Class Order:

- orderId

Class OrderLineItem:

- orderLineItemId
- productId
- date
- orderForeignKey
- embroidery_name

On the list view page of Order I want to be able to filter orders by whether or not the order's line items have an embroidery_name or not...

Comment: you can refer [django admin list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) 
this might solve your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best achieved by implementing a [`SimpleListFilter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) as Parth Modi mentions in the comments, and then specifying a `list_filter` attribute in your `OrderAdmin` class.

For example:

```
class EmptyEmbroideryNameFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = 'Embroidery Name'
    parameter_name = 'embroideryname'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [('not_set', 'Not set')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'not_set':
            return queryset.filter(
                orderlineitem__embroidery_name__isnull=True
            )
```

And then in your `OrderAdmin` class:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_filter = (EmptyEmbroideryNameFilter, )
```

You should then get a sidebar appear on the right hand side of the admin page where you can filter `Order`s that have `OrderLineItem`s without `embroidery_name`s.

Comment: That is what I came up with too. I had to modify though to prevent duplicates and return false if all were null

queryset.distinct().filter(orderlineitem__embroidery_name__isnull=False).exclude(orderlineitem__embroidery_name__isnull=True)